# Facet ElasticSearch on list of dict (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, facet, elasticsearch-aggregation, faceted-search

## Given

Data in index looks like

```
{
  "entity_tags": [
    {
      "tags": [
        "two",
        "three"
      ],
      "tag_data_type": "multitextselect",
      "tag_group_name": "one 3"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "new1"
      ],
      "tag_data_type": "textselect",
      "tag_group_name": "one"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "10"
      ],
      "tag_data_type": "counter",
      "tag_group_name": "new"
    }
  ],
  "class": "A"
}
```

I need to write a Elasticsearch query (facet) in python such that output will return ( Need to return all possible values)

1. class: [A], # as class contains A option only
2. new:[10] #  new contains10 option only
3. one:[new1] #  one contains new & new1 option only
4. one 3:[three, two] # one 3 contains two & three option only

For a list of dict (here entity_tags ) it should return all tag_group_name values with possible tags values

Note: Above data is a sample document in ElasticSearch I need to return all possible values that are returned in response to support dynamic filters

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @BlueRobin above data is sample document in ElasticSearch I need to return all possible value that are return in response to support dynamic filters

Comment: Please add that as apart of your question.